# how many resistance do i need to safe the LED of PC814?

Tags: arduino, led, resistance, opto-isolator

if i have a input of 5v (arduino HIGH) on the LED of a PC814, how is the value of the resistance that i must use before that, so i don't burn the led?

http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/Sharp/mXtzyru.pdf

i couldn't find the voltage that it supports on the datasheet, maybe i just don't know how to read it, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward voltage is listed as 1.2V (typical) at a forward current of 20mA.

This means that from a 5V drive voltage you need to have a resistor that "drops" 3.8V when conducting 20mA. This means it's resistance is 3.8/0.02 = 190 ohm

Considering that the peak forward current is 50mA, you should be OK with a 180 ohm resistor

Answer (score 1):

Under "Electro-optical characteristics", the datasheet shows a typical forward voltage of 1.2 volts, and the Absolute Maximum current is given as 50 mA.

The voltage across the series resistor will then be 5 - 1.2 = 3.8 volts, and you should design for a somewhat lower current than the Absolute Maximum - I'll say 30 mA, so by Ohm's Law, the resistor value will be 3.8V/.03A = 127 ohms.  The nearest standard resistor value is 120 Ohms.